# Angular.js Unit Testing Service Object

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

In our Angular Controller we have this:

```
vm = this
vm.wizardService = WizardService # injected service
pageAndFilter.AccountingRun = vm.wizardService.getAccountingRun()._id
```

How can I mock `vm.wizardService?`

I have this, but it won't work:

```
describe 'Controller: Accounting', ->

  beforeEach angular.mock.module('myApp')

  mockScope           = undefined
  $http               = undefined
  $httpBackend        = undefined
  $rootScope          = undefined
  $state              = undefined
  WizardService       = undefined
  vm                  = undefined

  beforeEach angular.mock.inject(($controller, _$rootScope_, _$http_, _$httpBackend_, _$state_, _WizardService_, _vm_) ->

    mockScope          = _$rootScope_.$new()
    $http              = _$http_
    $httpBackend       = _$httpBackend_
    $rootScope         = _$rootScope_
    $state             = _$state_
    vm                 = _vm_
    WizardService      = _WizardService_

    AbrechnungController = $controller('AbrechnungController',
      $scope: mockScope, $httpBackend: $httpBackend, $rootScope:$rootScope, $state:$state
    )
  )

  beforeEach ->
    WizardServiceMock = () ->
      getAccountingRun: () ->
        return {
          '_id':123
        }
    spyOn(WizardService, 'getAccountingRun').and.callFake(WizardServiceMock)

  describe 'Scope Variables and Methods', ->
    it 'should have scope vars and functions defined', (done) ->
      vm.wizardService = WizardService
      expect(vm.wizardService).toBeDefined()
      done()
```

Comment: When you instantiate the controller you are not adding the WizardService instance to the dependencies. In fact i don't think that you need to require it on the inject function. Would be enough to pass an object with the API fully mocked. If you want to test the service this should be done directly and not on the controller test

Comment: Noted. I will post updated code soon. I made some progress.